# how to use Angularjs to generate a list of sequential number in the inner loop

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 ng-repeat nested one in another.

```
<div ng-repeat='x in categories'>
   <span>x.name</span>
   <div ng-repeat='y in items'>
      <p>{{ how to write the expression here ?}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

So I want to have it look like:

```
Food
  1
  2
  3
Water
  4
  5
Vegy
  6
  7
etc...
```

Can anybody figure it out?

Thank you.

Comment: how items are related to categories ?

Comment: hi @sylwester an item instance has category_id to refer to its category.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this just using CSS, irrespective of what items belongs to:

**CSS**:

```
body {
  counter-reset: items;
}
.item:before {
  counter-increment: items;
  content: counter(items) ".\00A0\00A0";
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-repeat='x in categories'>
  <div ng-repeat='y in items'>
    <p class="item"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FWjvx9WDbQ8Crls2X7Cl?p=preview).

Comment: Hi scarlz, it looks so succinct :) I tried it but no numbers display and no errors to debug....

Comment: Not sure why you're not seeing the expected result - I've added a working plunker to my response.